# What is the actual difference between the different HTTP request methods besides semantics?

Tags: http, post, methods, get, put

I have read many discussions on this, such as the fact the PUT is idempotent and POST is not, etc. However, doesn't this ultimately depend on how the server is implemented? A developer can always build the backend server such that the PUT request is not idempotent and creates multiple records for multiple requests. A developer can also build an endpoint for a PUT request such that it acts like a DELETE request and deletes a record in the database.

So my question is, considering that we don't take into account any server side code, is there any real difference between the HTTP methods? For example, GET and POST have real differences in that you can't send a body using a GET request, but you can send a body using a POST request. Also, from my understanding, GET requests are usually cached by default in most browsers.

Are HTTP request methods anything more than just a logical structure (semantics) so that as developers we can "expect" a certain behavior based on the type of HTTP request we send?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that most of the differences are on the semantic level, and if your components decide to assign other semantics, this will work as well. *Unless* there are components involved that you do not control (libraries, proxies, load balancers, etc).

For instance, some component might take advantage of the fact that PUT it idempotent and thus can re retried, while POST is not.

Answer (score -1):

The Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) is designed to enable communications between clients and servers.

HTTP works as a request-response protocol between a client and server.

A web browser may be the client, and an application on a computer that hosts a web site may be the server.

Example: A client (browser) submits an HTTP request to the server; then the server returns a response to the client. The response contains status information about the request and may also contain the requested content.

HTTP Methods

GET

POST

PUT

HEAD

DELETE

PATCH

OPTIONS

The GET Method

GET is used to request data from a specified resource.

GET is one of the most common HTTP methods.

Note that the query string (name/value pairs) is sent in the URL of a GET request.

The POST Method

POST is used to send data to a server to create/update a resource.

The data sent to the server with POST is stored in the request body of the HTTP request.

POST is one of the most common HTTP methods.

The PUT Method

PUT is used to send data to a server to create/update a resource.

The difference between POST and PUT is that PUT requests are idempotent. That is, calling the same PUT request multiple times will always produce the same result. In contrast, calling a POST request repeatedly have side effects of creating the same resource multiple times.

The HEAD Method

HEAD is almost identical to GET, but without the response body.

In other words, if GET /users returns a list of users, then HEAD /users will make the same request but will not return the list of users.

HEAD requests are useful for checking what a GET request will return before actually making a GET request - like before downloading a large file or response body.

The DELETE Method

The DELETE method deletes the specified resource.

The OPTIONS Method

The OPTIONS method describes the communication options for the target resource.

src. w3schools